# jq pipe operator in nested array

Tags: jq

Using code below to pull data from a local json file.

The file is very large and is nested with objects and arrays.  There are multiple objects in the `.ratings[]` that I would like to extract.

How can I use the pipe operator in the `.ratings[]` array so that I don't have to retype `.ratings[]` for each piece of data that I would like to pull?

```
jq -r '.players[] | [.firstName,.lastName,.tid,.pid,.ratings[].spd,.ratings[].jmp] | join(", ")'
```

Comment: Do you want 1 line per player or 1 line per rating (with player names duplicated)?

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose it in `()` to use the pipe sign:

```
.players[] | [.firstName, .lastName, .tid, .pid, (.ratings[] | .spd, .jmp)] | join(", ")
```

---

###### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/y-e07l0cbb)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the expected output, so it is not clear if your proposed solution gives you the output you want.

Given the following input:

```json
{
  "players": [
    {
      "firstName": "fname1",
      "lastName": "lname1",
      "tid": "tid1",
      "pid": "pid1",
      "ratings": [
        {
          "spd": "spd1-1",
          "jmp": "jmp1-1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "firstName": "fname2",
      "lastName": "lname2",
      "tid": "tid2",
      "pid": "pid2",
      "ratings": [
        {
          "spd": "spd2-1",
          "jmp": "jmp2-1"
        },
        {
          "spd": "spd2-2",
          "jmp": "jmp2-2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "firstName": "fname3",
      "lastName": "lname3",
      "tid": "tid3",
      "pid": "pid3",
      "ratings": [
        {
          "spd": "spd3-1",
          "jmp": "jmp3-2"
        },
        {
          "spd": "spd3-2",
          "jmp": "jmp3-2"
        },
        {
          "spd": "spd3-3",
          "jmp": "jmp3-3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Your solution and the [answer from 0ston0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72013670/112968) will give you 1 line per player, but a different number of columns per line:

```
.players[] | [.firstName,.lastName,.tid,.pid,(.ratings[]|.spd,.jmp)] | join(", ")
```

generates:

```
fname1, lname1, tid1, pid1, spd1-1, jmp1-1
fname2, lname2, tid2, pid2, spd2-1, jmp2-1, spd2-2, jmp2-2
fname3, lname3, tid3, pid3, spd3-1, jmp3-2, spd3-2, jmp3-2, spd3-3, jmp3-3
```

This might or might not be what want your result to look like.

A different solution will print one line per rating, but duplicate the players' names. Running:

```
.players[] | [.firstName,.lastName,.tid,.pid] + (.ratings[]|[.spd,.jmp]) | join(", ")
```

will result in:

```
fname1, lname1, tid1, pid1, spd1-1, jmp1-1
fname2, lname2, tid2, pid2, spd2-1, jmp2-1
fname2, lname2, tid2, pid2, spd2-2, jmp2-2
fname3, lname3, tid3, pid3, spd3-1, jmp3-2
fname3, lname3, tid3, pid3, spd3-2, jmp3-2
fname3, lname3, tid3, pid3, spd3-3, jmp3-3
```

Both solutions are valid for different use cases and depending on how you are going to subsequently process the data.